# Python. How to execute a system command(Windows) avioding console?

Tags: python, windows, console

Now I'm running my scrypt with pythonw.exe and when the following command is executing cmd appears:

```
r = subprocess.call('net stop tomcat7', shell=False)
print r
```

How to make cmd not appear when code executing?

Comment: Try with `shell = True`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set shell parameter 'True'.

```
r = subprocess.call('net stop tomcat7', shell=True)  
print r
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this startupinfo with subprocess.Popen (in [this project](https://github.com/jasonsperske/PubNubBlink/blob/master/PubNubBlink.py)):

```
subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 1
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

subprocess.Popen(
    [app] + args,
    startupinfo=startupinfo,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```